# node request-promise doesn't work with pipe() for a POST request with body

Tags: javascript, node.js, request-promise

My service dispatches a `POST` request with some body coming from one service to another. Existing implementation works for `GET` request:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

public pipe(options: Options, req: Request, res: Response): void {
  rp(options).pipe(res);
}
```

I wanted to use it for `POST` requests as well. Unfortunately it doesn't work when I'm passing a body to `options`. Method `public pipe(options: Options, req: Request, res: Response)` is reached, but no further request is coming out of my service. Without body a request is dispatched properly. I'm calling this method like this:

```
streamFromService(
req: Request,
res: Response,
serviceId: string,
servicePath: string,
query?: URLSearchParams): void {
const forwardHeaders = getForwardHeaders(req);
Promise.resolve(this.serviceLookup.lookup(serviceId, req.headers))
  // create URL parameter based on the given method parameters
  .then((url) =>
    query
      ? { ...url, pathname: servicePath, search: query.toString() }
      : { ...url, pathname: servicePath }
  )
  // create the URL
  .then((url: any) => URL.format(url))
  // tap(c => console.log('URL>', c)).
  .then((url) => {
        req.method.toUpperCase() === 'POST' ?
            this.httpClient.pipe(
                {method: 'POST', body: req.body, url: url, headers: forwardHeaders},
                req,
                res
            ) :
            this.httpClient.pipe(
                {url: url, headers: forwardHeaders},
                req,
                res
            );
      }
  )
  // tap(console.log).
  .tapCatch((err) =>
    console.error('Error for ', serviceId, servicePath, err)
  );}
```

What is worth mentioning is that before calling `pipe()` I'm retrieving some information from `req` like for mapping headers with `req.headers`.
Is there a solution for my problem in piping a post request with body?

Comment: What does 'not work' mean?  Have you checked that the `method` is indeed `POST` for the relevant `pipe` call to be made?  Have you checked that the first object argument is correctly formatterd for the API?  Are you able to check to see what form the request is in, whether its handled correctly by the server?

Comment: @DaveMeehan thanks for your response - when I make a request to that service it looks like it reaches the `pipe(options: Options, req: Request, res: Response)` method but no further request is being made coming out of that service. I am pretty sure about the structure of that call, as well as about making an actual `POST` call. I've tested a similar implementation but without passing `req.body` to options. In that case request was dispatched properly.

Comment: I'm confused about which API's you are using, `request-promise` is marked as deprecated, as its is underlying `request` package which contains pipe.  There is even a note in the readme saying that streaming a response to pipe is discouraged.  Perhaps it would be better to evaluate whether there are better replacements for what you need?

Comment: @DaveMeehan I guess you're right. I wanted to use this library to fit existing implementation but I'll take a different approach on this post request, without relying on deprecated library. Thanks for suggestions.